# How to immediately reload UICollectionView Cells once certain conditions are met

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, reloaddata

I am trying to build a simple level design but I'm having some trouble reloading the data in the cells immediately when a condition is met. The user can choose to unlock levels they don't have enough points for yet by using a secondary game currency (stars). When they click a locked level they have the option to unlock it if they have enough stars.

The problem I'm having is that the level does not immediately unlock once the modal is dismissed I have to change views and then return back to the levels collection view in order for the cells to reload the data

my Storyboard: 
[image]

My code below:
ViewController

```
import UIKit

var stars = 10
var points = 11
var completeLevels:[String] = []

let levels = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate
{


@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    if points >= 10
    {
        completeLevels.append(levels[0])
    }
    if points >= 20
    {
        completeLevels.append(levels[1])
    }
    if points >= 30
    {
        completeLevels.append(levels[2])
    }
    if points >= 40
    {
        completeLevels.append(levels[3])
    }
    if points >= 50
    {
        completeLevels.append(levels[4])
    }
    if points >= 60
    {
        completeLevels.append(levels[5])
    }
    if points >= 70
    {
        completeLevels.append(levels[6])
    }
    if points >= 80
    {
        completeLevels.append(levels[7])
    }
    if points >= 90
    {
        completeLevels.append(levels[8])
    }
    completeLevels = Array(Set(completeLevels)).sorted()

    collectionView.reloadData()

}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool
{
    return true
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return levels.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! LevelCollectionViewCell
    cell.levelName.text = levels[indexPath.row]

    cell.lockedLevel.alpha = 1
    for objects in completeLevels
    {
        if levels.contains(objects)
        {
            if levels.index(of: objects) == indexPath.row
            {
                cell.lockedLevel.alpha = 0

            }


        }
    }


    return cell
}

 }
```

levelCollectionViewCell

```
 import UIKit

 class LevelCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell
 {
     @IBOutlet weak var lockedLevel: UIButton!
     @IBOutlet weak var levelName: UILabel!


 }
```

modalViewController

```
 import UIKit

 class modalViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func dismissModal(_ sender: Any)
{
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBOutlet weak var noStarsLabel: UILabel!
@IBAction func back(_ sender: Any)
{
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func unlockLevel(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    if stars >= 10
    {

        points += 10
        stars -= 10

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }else{
        noStarsLabel.text = "NOT ENOUGH STARS !"
    }
}


override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool
{
    return true
}

}
```

gameViewController (to simulate getting points and stars in the full game)

```
import UIKit

class gameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func addStars(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    stars += 10
}

@IBAction func addPoints(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    points += 10
}

}
```

Comment: Do you mean `collectionView.reloadData()`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a stored reference to your modalViewController in anywhere in the code you shared.  However the best way to handle this would be to change your `@IBAction func dismissModal(_ sender: Any)` to :

```
@IBAction func back(_ sender: Any)
{
    collectionView.reloadData()
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now, depending on which/what VC is presenting your modalViewController you may have to create a protocol to handle the reload, or store a reference in your modal when it is created that is up to you, but it sounds like you want the collectionView to update it's data/view after the user makes their choice, this is how I would handle this.

You could also override UIViewController's `viewWillDisappear` to trigger reloading your collectionView:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```